# How is $x \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ the same as $x \equiv 4\pmod{12}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

How is $x \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ the same as $x \equiv 6\pmod{12}?$

How too is $x \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ the same as $x \equiv 6\pmod{12}$ or $x \equiv 2\pmod{12}$ or $x \equiv 10\pmod{12}?$

Comment: It's not the same. $x\equiv 6\pmod{12}$ is equivalent to "$x\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod{3}$".

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the same.  $x \equiv 6 \pmod {12}$ implies $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ but not the other way around.  For example, $2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ ,but $n \not \equiv 6 \pmod {12}$.  Given any $x=6+12k$ if we take $x \bmod 4$ we get $2$.

Your added statement is true.  Given $x=2+4k$, depending on what $k \mod 3$ is we can get $x \equiv 2,6,10 \pmod {12}$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't: what is true is that $x\equiv2\pmod4$ is the same
as $3x\equiv6\pmod{12}$. The latter means $\frac1{12}(3x-6)\in\Bbb Z$,
which is the same as $\frac14(x-2)\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. If $x\equiv 6$ mod $12$, then $x=12n+6=4(3n+1)+2$, for some $n\in\mathbb Z$, so $x\equiv 2$ mod $4$. But the same implication doesn't work in reverse, e.g. $2\not\equiv 6$ mod $12$.

Comment: Okay, would there be a way of deducing this by inspection, or would you have to preform the arithmetic mentioned?

Comment: If you have $x\equiv a$ mod $n$, and want to conclude $x\equiv b$ mod $m$, there's no hope unless $m$ divides $n$. So this might work going from mod $12$ to mod $4$, but certainly not the other way. If $m$ does divide $n$, then it works if and only if $a\equiv b$ mod $m$. Here $6\equiv 2$ mod $4$, and $12$ is a multiple of $4$, so knowing $x\equiv 6$ mod $12$ implies $x\equiv 6$ mod $4$, which implies $x\equiv 2$ mod $4$.